# Publish to multiple users wall using stream.publish not working

Tags: facebook

I am trying to post a same message to multiple friends using stream.publish.. I am sending friends ids as a comma separated list to the parameter target_id.. but it seems not working and the publising is happening only in the first friends wall..

Is it a normal behavior and should I call stream.publish for each friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which API you are using to publish stream. But I think you need to call stream.publish for each friend according to DPP, can have a look at http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/371 and http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. ok so I will loop through the selected user ids and post to each user separately. i need to do this even though DPP is telling its bad.. but its not a spamming app ;). Thanks